# BackgroundWorker ReportProgress race condition

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

The code below is the most basic example of BackgroundWorker.

So basically there are two threads: one main and one worker thread. Whenever the worker thread calls ReportProgress, the bw_ProgressChanged is invoked on the main thread (it's the way BackgroundWorker works).

If the worker thread is calling the ReportProgress without any delays, the main thread doesn't handle the bw_ProgressChanged calls in order. Can someone explain more in depth why this is happening?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace _0042_BackgroundWorkerReportProgress
{
    class Program
    {
        static BackgroundWorker _bw;

        static void Main()
        {
            _bw = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };
            _bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            _bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
            _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

            _bw.RunWorkerAsync("Hello to worker");

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter in the next 5 seconds to cancel");
            Console.ReadLine();
            if (_bw.IsBusy) _bw.CancelAsync();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 20)
            {
                if (_bw.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; return; }
                _bw.ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);  // Without this, there is a race condition.
            }                            
            e.Result = 123;
        }

        static void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
                Console.WriteLine("You canceled!");
            else if (e.Error != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Worker exception: " + e.Error.ToString());
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Complete: " + e.Result);
        }

        static void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reached " + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BackgroundWorker was designed to be useful in a GUI app, the kind of app that *requires* thread-safe use of the UI.  It cannot help in a console mode app, the event handler runs on an arbitrary worker thread because the required plumbing is missing.  Yes, that makes it look like it races.  It is not obvious at all why you want to use it, the console is thread-safe.

Comment: I don't use this particular code anywhere. This is just an example. I was just curious of the behavior that this code produces.

Answer (score 0):

The [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) captures the current `SynchronizationContext` at the moment its `RunWorkerAsync` is called ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs.html#442b5ba237feb20f)). When the `ReportProgress` method is called ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs.html#41adc96c46a78dda)), it invokes the `ProgressChanged` event by posting to the previously captured `SynchronizationContext`. If there was no `SynchronizationContext.Current` to capture (which happens by default in a Console application), an instance of the base [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) class is created and stored as captured context:

> The `SynchronizationContext` class is a base class that provides a free-threaded context with no synchronization.

Which means that the `ProgressChanged` event is invoked in a random `ThreadPool` thread.

If you want to use the `BackgroundWorker` class in a Console application, and have it behave in a similar way with a WinForms/WPF application, you must install a `SynchronizationContext` implementation that is not free-threaded. You can find a suitable implementation [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/).